# Nosetest coverage not showing classes starting with Test

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

Im generating a coverage report with nosetest using the following command:

```
nosetests --exe --with-coverage --cover-html --cover-package=Mypackage Tests/
```

In my tests Im using some classes and almost all classes are found except one thats called:

```
TestCasesFilter
```

After trying some thigns I found out that when I rename the class to something else e.g OneTestCasesFilter the class is added to the coverage report.
Our naming convention requires us to name the class after the table in the datbase that is written to so in this case TestCases. Is it possible to add the class to the coverage report without renaming the class?

Im using:

```
python 2.7.14
coverage 4.4.1
nose 1.3.7
```

Comment: Please include some more of the code of `TestCasesFilter`. eg. `class TestCasesFilter(unittest.TestCase):`

Comment: @quamrana TestCaseFilter is the class I want to test , not the file of the test so it has object as base class. I dont want t ocomplicate the question as I think the content of TestCaseFilter does not mather, the problem is the name as it starts with Test (I guess)

Comment: Have you also tried renaming a different class which currently *does* appear in the coverage report to see if that one disappears?

Comment: @quamrana good suggestion, I tried it and when I prepend Test to the name the classes are not displayed in the coverage report anymore

Comment: So, could be a problem with nosetest, or a configuration problem that mistakes your class for a test class. (or within `py coverage`).

Comment: Seeing the same problem while trying to unittest a class called TestBase.  Interestingly, it does show up in the list when I run coverage report after I'm done running nosetests, so it's in the .coverage file - it's just not in the little report that nosetests prints out

Answer (score 0):

### Background

My setup is a bit different than yours, but I was seeing a similar problem.  I have a setup.cfg file in the root of my python package that looks like this:

`[nosetests]
with-coverage=1
cover-xml=1
cover-xml-file=coverage.xml
cover-package=companyname`

With this setup.cfg file, I was not seeing companyname/test_base.py show up in the coverage report that nosetests spits out at the end.  I was, however, seeing it show up when I ran `coverage report` so I know the data is being collected.

#### My Fix

Looking at [the documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html) I saw a couple of potential options to fix.  I was able to resolve the issue by adding `cover-tests=1` to my setup.cfg file. The docs describe this option as

`--cover-tests
    Include test modules in coverage report`

It looks like whatever algorithm nose uses to determine what is a "test" isn't very smart and maybe only looks at class names

#### Your Fix

Since you're using the command-line to pass options, I think you need to add --cover-tests when you invoke nosetests